# Change the index of selected icon in Persistent Bottom Navbar without opening the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar package in my project. Everything works great, but I recently got the need to change the selected icon dynamically.

My navigation bar holds the following items:

Dashboard Icon • Customers Icon • Shop Icon • Account Icon

Inside the screen `Customers` I have a button that goes into another screen called `CustomersReports`.

---

Inside dashboard screen I have a button which allow me to open directly the `CustomersReports` and I would like to focus immediatelly the `Customers Icon` in my navigation bar, otherwise it keeps the `Dashboard icon` as selected.

The button holds the following code:

```
onPressed: () {
  PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
    context,
    screen: CustomersReports(),
    withNavBar: true,
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
  );
},
```

I also tried to pass a callback that would change the Tab Index dynamically, but the problem is that the screen is opened!

```
onPressed: () {
  PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(
    context,
    screen: CustomersReports(),
    withNavBar: true,
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
  );
  
  widget.switchTabIndex(1); // Where "1" is the Customers Icon
},
```

And then, using the `PersistentTabController`:

```
return PersistentTabView(
  context,
  controller: tabController,
  screens: 
  [
    DashboardScreen(
      switchTabIndex: (int screenIndex) {
        tabController.jumpToTab(screenIndex); // Opens the screen "Customers"
        tabController.index = screenIndex; // Also opens the screen "Customers"
      },
    ),
    CustomersScreen(),  
  ],
  items: navbarItems(),
  ...
);
```

Both `tabController.jumpToTab` & `tabController.index` forces `CustomersScreen` to open.

Is there any way to only focus the icon? The `PersistentBottomNavBarItem` doesn't seem to have any property that would allow me to do what I want:

```
PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
    activeColorPrimary: Colors.yellow,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

I had to use the [Custom Navigation Bar Styling](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#custom-navigation-bar-styling) approach.

1 - First assign a global variable to save the current selected index

```
int selectedIndex = 0;
```

2 - Create the custom Persistent Tab View

```
return PersistentTabView.custom(
  context,
  controller: tabController,
  itemCount: items().length,
  screens: screens(),
  ....
  customWidget: MyCustomNavigationBar(
    items: items(),
    selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
    onItemSelected: (index) {
      setState(() {     
          selectedIndex = index;
          tabController.index = selectedIndex;
      });
    },
  ),
);
```

3 - Assign a callback to the dashboard screen to update the selected index

```
List<Widget> screens() {
    return [
      DashboardScreen(
        onScreenChanged: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),      
    ];
}
```